# C++: writing a function for a struct outside that struct?

Tags: c++, struct

For classes, you could just say:

```
class Test{
    int a;
    Test(int a);
}

Test::Test(int a) {
    this->a=a;
}
```

Function names get "classname::" in front of them when declared outside of class.

How would I do this for structs?

```
struct Test {
    int a;
    Test(int a);
}
```

How would I write the function for this struct Test outside of struct declaration so that it can be only be called by a Test struct?

Comment: The difference between structs and classes is that struct members are public by default. But class members are private by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, `struct`s are essentially the same as `class`es except for their default protection levels: `class`es default to `private`, `struct`s to `public`. To define that function outside of the `struct` so that it can only be called from a member, declare it as private, then define it as normal:

```
struct Test {
private:
    int a;
    Test(int a);
};

Test::Test(int a) {
    this->a=a;
}
```

Additionally, instead of modifying the `a` member in the constructor body like that, you should use an *initializer list*. This sets the value of the member *before* the instance is fully constructed. It's not so important with just an `int`, but it's a good practice to get in to.

```
struct Test {
private:
    Test(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Same way. Difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is only default visibility of members (private for `class`, public for `struct`).

Actually, it's not just function, it's constructor of `class`/`struct` `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I write the function for this struct Test outside of struct declaration

Do exactly what you did for the first one. Both are class types, whether you use the `class` or `struct` keyword to introduce them.

The only difference is the default accessibility of members and base classes: private if you use `class`, and public if you use `struct`.

> so that it can be only be called by a Test struct?

If you mean that you want it to be private (as it is in the first example), then you'll have to do so explicitly, since accessibility defaults to public:

```
struct Test {
    int a;
private:
    Test(int a);
};
```

Personally, I'd use the more conventional `class` if there's anything non-public.

Answer (score 0):

ForEveR is right. Just like in the question you can have a structure member defined like:

```
struct Test{
    int a;
    Test(int a);
};

Test::Test(int a) {
    this->a=a;
}
```

point to note, struct members are public by default. class memebers are private by default.